# Redirecting multiple URL's to a subfolder using htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

What I trying to achieve is redirect my domain with `www` and without it to a subfolder in my application.

Example:
I have `www.mysite.in`.I want to redirect the user to `www.mysite.in/feature/index.php` when he hits either `www.mysite.in` or only `mysite.in`,but I am not able to achive it.I either end up in a loop or the redirect does not work.
This is what I have tried

```
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.in
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.in/feature/index.php$1 [R=301,L]


     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.in [NC] 
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.in/feature/index.php$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above ends in loop.

```
     Redirect 301 mysite.in http://www.mysite.in/feature/index.php
     Redirect 301 http://www.mysite.in http://www.mysite.in/feature/index.php
```

In the above case first redirect works,second fails.
How can I resolve the issue.?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 2 rules, as they redirect both to the same URL.
There is a loop because you don't test the folder you're in. The RewriteCond on HTTP_HOST is useless because you always be on mysite.in or www.mysite.in (if not leave it).
Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/feature/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.in/feature/index.php$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Will try it and revert! Thank you for the response